# VB Compare textbox to a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with data, and if i put a value in one textbox and try to insert that value, if the value already exist in the datagridview i want to show a msgbox. So, what i want is to run, line by line, the data of the datagridview and compares with the value in the textbox.

I already try to make, but i just got to compare the first line of the textbox, and what i want it's something that run automatically line by line and then compare with the value in the textbox.
How i do that?!

thanks

Comment: Show your code please!

Comment: Hi Daniel Provide us with code please.
Read here about how to ask a quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: i already resolve my problem. Thanks for you attention